# Emacs/Lisp interactive string variable scoping

Tags: emacs, lisp

Why doesn't this work?

```
(defun load-browser (app)
    (interactive "sChoose Browser? ")
    (cond ((string= app '"c")
        (setq browse-url-generic-program "chromium")
        (setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic))
    (message "Else case Typed %s" app)
    )
)
```

It fails to work in the Else case where the input string/char is not "c".

Answer (score 1):

1. No need to quote a string: use `"c"` instead of `'"c"`.  Strings evaluate to themselves.
2. You second `cond` clause is invalid.  It is this: `(message "Else case Typed %s" app)`.  That tests the symbol `message` as a variable, and it is no doubt an undefined variable, which raises an error.

What you are probably trying to get is this as your second `cond` clause:

```
 (t (message "Else case Typed %s" app)) ; If not first clause, show message.
```

Read the doc about `cond`.  And always use correct indentation.  See `C-h k C-M-q` in Emacs-Lisp mode.

Comment: That should be `C-h k C-M-q`. I tried to edit it, but apparently edits have to be at least six characters.

Comment: @jbm: Right; thanks. Corrected C-h f to C-h k.